# Integration $\displaystyle\int \frac{x^8 ( x+1) ^6- 256}{x-2} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

This integration I tried to solve it.  And I did but.  By using the dividing .. the question is how we can solve this integration without dividing???
$$\int \frac{x^8 (x+1)^6 - 256}{x-2} \, dx$$ ..  is there any hint??? ..  thanks everyone

Answer (score 3):

I would break the integral up using the rule of sum. First, note that:

$$\int \dfrac{x^{8} (x+1)^{6} - 256}{x-2} dx = \int \dfrac{x^{8} (x+1)^{6}}{x-2} dx - 256 \int \dfrac{1}{x-2} dx$$

The second integral is easy to evaluate.

Now by the binomial theorem, we have:

$$(x+1)^{6} = \sum_{i=0}^{6} \binom{6}{i} x^{i}$$

So:

$$\int \dfrac{x^{8}(x+1)^{6}}{x-2} = \sum_{i=0}^{6} \binom{6}{i} \biggr ( \int \dfrac{x^{8+i}}{x-2} dx \biggr )$$

We set $u = x - 2$ and $du = dx$. So $x^{8+i} = (u+2)^{8+i}$ and

$$\int \dfrac{x^{8+i}}{x-2} dx = \int \dfrac{(u+2)^{8+i}}{u} du$$

You get to apply the binomial theorem again on:

$$\int \dfrac{(u+2)^{8+i}}{u} du$$

It's then a matter of collecting terms. I ran it on Wolfram Alpha, and there was a series expansion containing a dozen terms in the final answer for your original question. But I've basically done the hard work here.

Comment: That is great work..  but I don't know why the question has many down vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: substitute $u=x-2$, then expand, then integrate.

Comment: That would still be dividing, it just makes the dividing much easier.

Comment: It is not a critique or a request, it is a hint, which is what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $$\int\frac{x^8(x+1)^6-256}{x-2}dx$$ Let $x-2=t \implies dx=dt$ $$\int\frac{(t+2)^8(t+3)^6-256}{t}dt$$ Can you take it from here?